# Angular 2 pagination

Tags: angular

I am using ngx pagination. When I pass `(pageChange)="p = $event"` it helps me to change navigation list, but I want to send `p` value in a function like `(pageChange)="pageChange(p)"` and perform `p = $event` in that function in component.

Please help how do I achieve it.

```js
// want to do 

pageChange(p) {
    p = $event;
  }
```

```html
<!-- current function -->

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>


<!-- want to do -->

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChange(p)"></pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to pass the event, not p:

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"></pagination-controls>

pageChange($event) {
  this.p = $event;
}
```